# IBM Worklight Cordova ChildBrowser Error

Tags: cordova, xcode4.5, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using "http://clearblade.wordpress.com/2012/07/31/using-worklight-with-cordova-childbrowser-plugin/#comment-152" this url to access IBM Worklight Corodova ChildBrowser functionality in iPhone.these steps are running fine if we have just xcode project, it faced error when generating from Worklight.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, right off the bat, I can see you are missing the Plugins folder. Take a look at this tutorial, which walks you step by step on how to do it: http://moduscreate.com/opening-all-urls-with-phonegaps-childbrowser-plugin/

I also wrote a post on how I did it, which includes the steps on that post.

Lastly, remember that when you work in Xcode, you are altering the WL folders/files, so you need to rebuild the application before running in WL Studio/Eclipse.